# Stochastic matrix with probability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, transition-matrix

This is my first time looking at this material

> On any given​ day, a student is either healthy or ill. Of the students who are healthy​ today, 95​% will be healthy tomorrow. Of the students who are ill​ today, 60​% will still be ill tomorrow.
>
> 1. Find the stochastic matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    .95 &  .40 \\
    .05 &  .60 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

> 2. Suppose 20% of the students are ill on Monday. What percentage of the students are likely to be ill on​ Tuesday? On​ Wednesday?

No clue what the arithmetic is. I think I take the stochastic matrix and multiply it by:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    .20 \\
    .80 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

which would give :

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    .51 \\
    .49 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then rounded to the nearest tenth the percentage of students ill on monday would be .5? correct?

Is this correct? Am I doing this right?

Then to find out the likely to be ill on Wed I just take stochastic matrix from part one and multiply it by the resulting matrix of part two?

Comment: you are right about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is transposed from the usual form; see a description of how to build the stochastic matrix associated with a Markov chain [here, for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix).  In the typical setting, probability distributions are treated as row vectors.  For your version of the transition matrix, probability distributions are treated as column vectors. I will stick to your convention.

Given a probability distribution $p = (p_1,p_2)^T$ (proportion of healthy/sick students), the distribution after one day (i.e. after one step of the Markov chain) is given by $Mp$, which is what you computed.  In other words, the product you computed is correct.

The product for Wednesday will be $M(Mp) = M^2p$, which seems to be what you describe in your post.